# How does one write the possesive form of stock ticker symbols ending in "s"?

Tags: punctuation, possessives, apostrophe

How does one write the possessive form of stock ticker symbols ending in "s"?

These are neither acronyms nor initialisms (/TLAs). For instance, does one write **RAS'** earnings, or **RAS's** earnings?

Comment: You write it exactly as you would say it. You can't possibly write *RAS' earnings* if you actually say *RAS's earnings*, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Katherine Fry and Rowena Kirton's grammar book ***Grammar for Grown-Ups*** says

> There can be a problem with names ending in **'s'**, but write it as it's pronounced, so:
>
> - Morris's wallpaper,
> - Iris's house,
> - Dickens's book,
> - *The Times*'s conservative leaning.
>
> However, because this is a modern practice, and it was formerly customary to leave off that extra **'s'**, classical and historical names still omit them on the whole. So:
>
> - Aeschylus' plays,
> - Oedipus' mother,
> - Moses' toes,
> - Jesus' sandals.

Thus, RegDwighт's comment is correct -- but just notice the **classical and historical** case. BTW, as a non-native speaker, I am not clear when the 's' should be pronounced. For example, I saw **Jobs's** (in Isaacson's book ***Steve Jobs***) and I can *feel* it weird if I don't pronounce the possessive 's'; however, I also saw **Jobses'**, which conflicted with *my feeling*. So, is there any rule formulating when the possessive 's' should be pronounce? Thanks for all comments.

Comment: I've found both Athens' and Athens's. Does this mean the city is now considered a modern one?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I've no idea about this. But ... is it a joke? Punctuation wouldn't be supposed to bear so much significance.

Comment: I remember reading about the s' to s's switch - I believe it was in Truss's _Eats Shoots and Leaves_. I began thinking about the point across the Atlantic at which one should switch from UK to US English

Answer (score 0):

Abbreviations, acronyms, initialisms, alphabetisms, and all short forms of the type should be treated as such, and not as grammatical "words" of the language.

The singular exception is those that are no longer capitalized (not even initial capital) and pronounced as words.

In the first instance, *always* append and apostrophe-s for the possessive: **RAS's**.

In the case of the exceptions, apply the rules of punctuation treating it as any other word.

Do you know *ichthys'* origin?

> Acronymy has ancient roots, as illustrated by the early Christian use of the Greek word *ichthys* meaning 'fish' as an acronym for *Iēsous Christos, Theou Huios, Sōtēr* ('Jesus Christ, God's son, Savior').  ([grammar.about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/acronymterm.htm))

Comment: The jargon [grammatical words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_word) is a little incomprehensible for me. And it seems your definition is a little different from that in the wiki page.

Comment: @Stan :) Most times, it's enough to understand a sentence in its plainest -- I merely meant 'words that are grammatical,' not a jargon phrase, certainly not what you have taken the trouble of looking up on WP! Notice the scare quotes there?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation with patience. I get it now. (And once "again", wiki helps me understand the meaning of `scare quotes` :p)

Comment: what is an alphabetism, please ????????????? (question marks added to meet the minimum character requirement)

Comment: @user44832  Please see https://www.thefreedictionary.com/alphabetism